# How to make a comic in blender?

Tags: freestyle, npr

I'm new on blender, I'm not animator or anything like that. I like comics and I was searching a different way to make them. I used blender years ago just for fun, to make a character walk, but, I never did more than that. I saw this on the blender: [image: Super awesome image]

I didn't know that blender could do that. I like the mix between 3d and 2d, I'm thinking about trying a comic with that and maybe if I can learn more, a entire short movie or animation. But first the comic.
So how should I start? Can someone recommend me some books or videos tutorial to make that kind of things, put 2d over 3d  (I already know the basic to modeling and texturing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something I am focused on but I would just watch / read some tutorials on Grease Pencil, especially these lessons should be useful for you:
https://vimeo.com/channels/greasepenciltuts

Also read the Blender's documentation on this topic:
https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/grease_pencil/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but [Link only answers are discouraged here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). If the links change, go dead or become unreachable your answer becomes empty and useless for possible future visitors. Either post it as a comment instead, or elaborate on the content and write something locally about it.